# How to add footer in massage Page?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

In [message Page demo](http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/sapui5-sdk-dist/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessagePage/preview) , it uses ComponentContainer(Component.js) to include massage page, but I want to add **footer** in this page , I tried

```
<mvc:View
   controllerName="cts.mobile.controller.Connect"
   height="100%"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
   xmlns="sap.m">

<Page>
    <content>
        <MessagePage 
            text="Disconnected"
            description="Click the Search Button"
            showHeader="false"
            showNavButton="true"
            icon="sap-icon://disconnected" > 

        </MessagePage>
    </content>
    <footer>
        <Toolbar>
            <Button text="Search" />
        </Toolbar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

But it seems the message page is covered by new page and disappeared, what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the 100% height css issue. You can inner Elements set to 100% height, but the page don´t know what 100% height mean and show no footer.

Example: http://jsbin.com/lohenoj/1/edit

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer , but I deleted `app.setHeight("500px");` in you demo and found that is does not matters that whether I add `height="100%"`. But it works when I add `<App>` in my xml view. Thanks for you inspirer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Markus's answer , I found that the problem is caused by my missing `<App>`, This code works:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="cts.mobile.controller.Connect"
height="100%"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">

<App>
    <Page
        id="page"
        navButtonPress="onNavBack"
        showNavButton="true"
        title="Connect Hitoe Transmitter">
        <content>
            <MessagePage 
                text="Disconnected"
                description="Click the Search Button"
                showHeader="false"
                showNavButton="true"
                icon="sap-icon://disconnected" > 

            </MessagePage>
        </content>
        <footer>
            <Toolbar>
                <Button text="Search" />
            </Toolbar>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</App>
```

I will mark my question as answered if anyone answered why this works.